# Dashed lines in pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting

pgr_dijkstra returns a dashed line. I tried with different databases and tables and always returns a dasher line.
Some explanation?
[image: pgRouting Layer]

Answer (score 6):

The reason for these kind of errors is ususally a wrong network topology. In particular you must make sure, that you use the correct unit (`meter` or `degree`) for the `tolerance` value in the `pgr_createTopology` function.

If the unit of your network geometry is for example `degree` and you set a tolerance of `1.0`, then nodes will snap if they are within 1 degree distance. If your geometry has `meter` as a unit, then a value of `1.0` would be totally fine.

https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_createTopology.html